# C++ how to check if matrix has floating element

Tags: c++, string, vector, getline

In my game I'm trying to make a Loss review 2 if some element of my 5x5 gameboard is floating i.e. all adjacent elements are empty (left, right, up, down).

So after removing element, program should check if some element is floating.

For example, if removing elements are in this order: [4,2], [5,3], [4,4], [3,3] game should be lost because element [4,3] will be floating so the Loss review 2 is true. But this does not work. If there some better way to make this?

(for making the board you need to input 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
// 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5

using namespace std; using Board = std::vector<vector<int>>;
const unsigned char EMPTY = ' ';

void initBoard(Board& board) {

cout << "Input: ";
string input = "";
getline(cin, input);

istringstream is { input };

    for (auto& row : board)
    {
        for(auto& column : row)
        {
        is >> column;
        }
    }
}

void printBoard(const Board& board) {

    cout << "=================" << endl;
    cout << "|   | 1 2 3 4 5 |" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
    for(unsigned int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
    {
        cout << "| " << row + 1 << " | ";
        for(unsigned int column = 0; column < 5; ++column)
        {
            if(board.at(row).at(column) == 0)
            {
                cout << EMPTY << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << board.at(row).at(column) << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    cout << "=================" << endl;
}

void updateBoard(Board& board) {

    int x, y;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter coordinates (x, y): ";
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;

            board.at(y-1).at(x-1) = 0;
            printBoard(board);

            // LOSS REVIEW 1: ADJACENT ELEMENT IS EMPTY
            if (x >= 1 && x <= 5 && y >= 1 && y <= 5) {

                        if ((y < 5 and board.at(x-1).at(y) == 0) or     // DOWN
                            (y > 1 and board.at(x-1).at(y-2) == 0) or   // UP
                            (x > 1 and board.at(x-2).at(y-1) == 0) or   // LEFT
                            (x < 5 and board.at(x).at(y-1) == 0)) {     // RIGHT
                            cout << "You lost" << endl;
                            return;
                        }
                        }
            // LOSS REVIEW 2: IF ALL ADJACENT ELEMENTS (left, right, up, down) OF ANY ELEMENT ARE EMPTY
            if (x >= 1 && x <= 5 && y >= 1 && y <= 5) {

                        if  ((x < 5 and y > 1 and board.at(x).at(y-2) == 0) and     // 1 element right and 1 element up from removed element
                            (x < 4 and board.at(x+1).at(y-1) == 0) and              // 2 elements right from removed element
                            (x < 5 and y < 5 and board.at(x).at(x) == 0)) {         // 1 element right and 1 element down from removed element
                            cout << "You lost" << endl;
                            return;
                        }
                        }
}
}

int main()
{
    Board board(5, vector<int>(5)); // board is vector with 3 rows and 3 columns
    initBoard(board);
    printBoard(board);
    updateBoard(board);

}
```

Comment: OT: In the definition `string input = "";` you don't need the initialization. A default-constructed `std::string` (like `std::string input;`) will be empty.

Comment: On another note: For debugging purposes, it often helps to hard-code the input inside the program. Like e.g. `std::string input = "1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5";` (and then skip the `std::getline` call).

Comment: You clear element at `[y][x]`, but check elements around `[x][y]`